# Error removing packages in Ubuntu using Synaptic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and during my tries to free space I've removed several packages such as: openoffice, all editors, and some more packages such as players and printers drivers that I don't need and seem o.k to remove. 
However, after restart, the graphical interface doesn't load, I'm in the xserver, I have console but not gui.
I was wondering if anyone can tell me which packages I should not remove or let me know of dependencies I need to consider when messing with packages?

Thanks!

Comment: If your on a terminal/console, then X didn't load.

Comment: when I try running startx, it says it's already running

Comment: We may be able to help you better if we know which packages are missing. Consider adding the output of `sudo apt-get install -s ubuntu-desktop-minimal` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you'd want to leave packages like xorg-* and gnome-session alone.

You could probably undo most of the damage by installing the `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` meta-package.
To simply get a listing of the missing packages without actually doing anything:

```
sudo apt-get install -s ubuntu-desktop
```